# Getting real and imaginary parts of complex function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I've got a following question. I've got function f(t) = C3*exp(t*x*1i) + C4*exp(-t*x*1i) as a solution of a differential equation (as syms). But I need this solution as a real function (C3*cos + C4*sin). How can I do it? And how can I get real and imaginary parts of this function? Is there a function in matlab allowing me to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`rewrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/rewrite.html) to rewrite the expression in terms of cosines and sines, then [`collect`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/collect.html) to collect coefficients in terms of `i`, giving you your real and imaginary terms:

```
f = C3*exp(t*x*1i) + C4*exp(-t*x*1i);
g = collect(rewrite(f, 'sincos'), i)

g =

(C3*sin(t*x) - C4*sin(t*x))*1i + C3*cos(t*x) + C4*cos(t*x)
```

You can see from the above that the imaginary term is zero if `C3` is equal to `C4`.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the expression/function in terms of sine and cosine using [`rewrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/rewrite.html). Still you cannot apply the [`real`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/real.html) and [`imag`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/imag.html) functions to get the respective parts in as nicer form as you get in case of non-symbolic computations. The trick to get the real and imaginary parts in a complex expression is to [substitute](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) [`i`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html) with `0` to get the real part and then subtract the real part from the original expression to get the imaginary part. Use [`simplify`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html) for the surety.

An example:

```
syms C3 C4 t x
f(t) = C3*exp(t*x*1i) + C4*exp(-t*x*1i);
fsincos = rewrite(f, 'sincos');
realf = simplify(subs(fsincos, i,0));
imagf = simplify(fsincos-realf);
%or you can use the collect function to avoid simplify
```

```
>> fsincos

fsincos(t) =

C3*(cos(t*x) + sin(t*x)*1i) + C4*(cos(t*x) - sin(t*x)*1i)
```

```
>> realf

realf(t) =

cos(t*x)*(C3 + C4)
```

```
>> imagf

imagf(t) =

sin(t*x)*(C3*1i - C4*1i)
```